# Android: Button change posistion when i view the app on different mobiles

Tags: android, button, layout

I have an activity with four buttons, when i play it on the emulator everything is OK, but when i test it on my mobile the buttons grow bigger or actually the background or the screen gets smaller but the buttons stay the same, so it looks bigger.

Can i make the buttons adapt with the screen the same way the background of the activist do?

Here is my xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mainn"
android:gravity="top" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_labor"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="114dp"
     android:background="@drawable/labb" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_mosul"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/b_labor"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b_labor"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
     android:background="@drawable/ninaa" />




<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_trafic"
    style="@style/Theme.Transparent"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/b_mosul"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b_mosul"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
     android:background="@drawable/traficc" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_nati"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/b_trafic"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b_trafic"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
    android:background="@drawable/natiii"

     />
```

Comment: The answer is yes. There is something that you are doing wrong (probably hard coding the width/height) can you post your XML/code, so we could help you?

Comment: I edit my question, i'm sorry i'm new here and new at android programming

Comment: use less hardcoding, then you can support multiple screen sizes,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are new to Android so you need to learn several things before creating UI elements on android devices. UI is not simple to create you should understand different concepts to create complex GUI in Android. The main problem in your above case is each device have different resolutions and if you Hard code your button then it will not adapt according to your device resolution and screen size. So before creating any UI element you need to keep some of the points in your mind:

1. Never try to hard code anything specially GUI parameters because these can change according to devices.
2. Always create and update your GUI from UIThread only.
3. Use asynchronous tasks, services and threads to perform heavy tasks and background tasks.
4. Always try to keep UI thread with minimum load.
5. To learn more about GUI characteristics try to explore LayoutParams for different layouts and views.

There are lot more thing you need to learn. According to me while creation of GUI you should start from Relative layouts and try not to use Absolute layout ever.

You can check below links for some help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992754/ui-design-tips-and-tutorials-for-android

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/26/android-design-tips/

Answer (score 0):

As we all are aware of different screen sizes of android devices , We should check for the alignment of buttons in different devices , For start check this link [Developer.google](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

There is stackoverflow answers , that will help you
 [screen size vs button position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131939/screen-sizes-vs-buttons-position)